# Алгоритм для школьников

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть две целочисленные переменные, a и b они могут быть произвольного диапазона, от 0 до 1млн.

Как  перенести эти числа в проценты, относительно друг, друга, что-бы потом добавить их в два дива, что-бы у каждого из них закрашенного было определенное расстояние стиль

```
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) /*Сюда*/, transparent 100%);
```

Например, a = 100, b = 50 в итоге у  дивов  будет

```
   -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) 100%, transparent 0%);
   -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) 50%, transparent 0%);
```

Comment: Причем тут школьники?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Узнаём какое число максимальное. (max, второе число соответственно min)
2. помечаем его как 100%
3. по элементарной формуле пропорций (x = (min*100)/max)

в итоге у нас будет 100 и Х

Comment: а как округлить?

Comment: http://javascript.ru/Math.round

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/85265/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-right_side-100-left_side